# Add sidebar to all pages except index in sphinx-bootstrap-theme

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have added a sidebar to my sphinx-documentation by appending the following to conf.py

```
html_sidebars = {'**': ['my_custom_sidebar.html']}
```

This causes the sidebar to show on *all* pages. 
I want this sidebar to show on all pages except the index page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

check this answer: [Sphinx exclude one Page from html_sidebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112812/sphinx-exclude-one-page-from-html-sidebars)

I got it to work using Chris Bay's code:

```
html_sidebars = {
'**': ['localtoc.html'],
'index': []
}
```