# Sphinx exclude one Page from html_sidebars

Tags: configuration, python-sphinx, glob

I am using Sphinx to build user docs for an application.  According to the documentation for build configuration file there is an html_sidebars setting with an example [documentaion](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-html_sidebars).

```
html_sidebars = {
'**': ['globaltoc.html', 'sourcelink.html', 'searchbox.html'],
'using/windows': ['windowssidebar.html', 'searchbox.html'],
}
```

I am looking to have all pages display the sidebar except one, I have only been able to achieve the inverse of that, where the sidebar appears on just one page and not the rest.

```
html_sidebars = {'index': ['localtoc.html']}
```

I know that its possible to use glob syntax and I've tried almost every variation of [!index] I can think of without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to have your expression match everything except the string 'index'. Unfortunately globbing is not that flexible. There are several ways of working around it.

1. explicitly list each file except index
2. rename the files that you want to have the sidebar with a prefix or suffix, and use a corresponding globbing pattern to match only those files
3. move the files into a subdirectory, and use a corresponding globbing pattern
4. try `[!x]`, assuming no other file has "x" in its name (i, n, d, and e are too common)
5. possibly something else?

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working with an exclude pattern I ended up having to list the other pages one by one, which is not ideal but this answer was technically correct.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and was able to achieve the desired result using:

```
html_sidebars = {
    '**': ['localtoc.html'],
    'index': []
}
```

Comment: I didn't get this to work before I changed the order. You can exploit that the entries are checked in order:

    html_sidebars = {
      'index': [],
      '**': ['localtoc.html']
    }